# SCRIPT5: Acces Denied jquery IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Scenario: Script to detect phone numbers on a given web page and highlight the phone numbers by an anchor tag.The script runs well in FF and Chrome, but fails in IE9 by throwing **SCRIPT5: Access denied** error.

**I have gone through other posts, hoping that it would solve my problem , but in vain.**

Below is my code:

```
var regex = /\+?\d{1,4}?[-.\s]?\(?\d{1,3}?\)?[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,9}/g;
jQuery.fn.linker = function () {
                        $(this).contents()
                               .filter(function(){return this.nodeType !== 3;})
                               .each(function(){$(this).linker();});



                        $(this).contents()
                               .filter(function() { return this.nodeType === 3; })
                               .each(function () {
                                    $(this).replaceWith(
                                    $(this).text().replace(regex,"<a href=\"javascript:;\">$&</a>"));});



                };
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('body').linker();
                    $( 'a' ).click( function () {
                        var href = $(this).text();
                        var tel = regex.test(href);
                        if ( tel ) {
                                //alert( 'A telephone link was clicked: ');
                                href = href.replace(/[(]\d[)]|[.-]/g,'');
                                //launchwebDialerServlet(href);
                                //alert(href);
                                //event.preventDefault();
                                //window.open($(this).attr('href'),"popupWindow","width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
                         }
                    });
                });
```

Below is the screenshot of the error
[image]
I hope,my question is clear.

Comment: It looks like the error has to do with your code attempting to access the contents of an `<iframe>` on the page.

Comment: @Pointy When i select `<body>` it throws `<iframe>` error, upon selecting a specific tag other than `<body>`...But I am unable to understand why it is throwing the iframe error.

Comment: I don't know what exactly the security situation is; IE may be more strict than Firefox and Chrome. It depends on what exact URL is loaded in the `<iframe>`.